# How to change 'pose' of mesh without rigging?

Tags: mesh, rigging, transforms, bones, edit-mode

I have a clothing that i want to fit onto my rigged character base mesh. Here is the sleeve, that i need to match the arm:
[image]

I've tried rotating it in Edit mode with Proportional Edit - kinda worked, but now it's stretched in some places, because it's not like rotating a bone. I guess the best solution will be to "pose" this sleeve to fit the arm, but is it possible without rigging whole clothing? The only thing i can think of is to create a single 'temporary' bone, rig the sleeve to it and then rotate & delete the bone... But maybe there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Why didn't proportional edit work? Its the same thing as the bone will do. Set the pivot point to elbow with 3D cursor, select the arm and set a proper falloff.

Comment: Ah, i forgot about setting pivot point in right place :) I will try it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that rigging with two bones is the easiest and fastest (adjustable) method to get the job done. Be sure to rig also all the vertices that need to nearly stay in place (they need to be assigned to two bones - one fixed and one moving -: one bone only would lead you to bad elbow joints!)